# Superstition about the adhan

Tags: adhan

If a person say or think of something negative and suddenly the adhan starts to give, does it mean that what he said or thought will become true??

Comment: What's the proof of your claim?. I have never heard of any such thing. In Islam there is no such thing as superstition.

Comment: Why did you re-post your question? consider deleting one instance!

Comment: Simple answer: It has no influence. You already said it is superstition, and so it is.

Answer (score -1):

Islam is not a religion of superstitions:

> وَحَدَّثَنِي عَنْ مَالِكٍ، أَنَّهُ بَلَغَهُ أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ تَرَكْتُ فِيكُمْ أَمْرَيْنِ لَنْ تَضِلُّوا مَا تَمَسَّكْتُمْ بِهِمَا كِتَابَ اللَّهِ وَسُنَّةَ نَبِيِّهِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> Yahya related to me from Malik that he heard that the Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, said, "I have left two matters with you. As long as you hold to them, you will not go the wrong way. **The Book of Allah and the Sunnah of His Prophet.**"

At least one of these is needed to back up a [religious] claim:

1. The Qur'an.
2. The Hadeeth (with authentic chain of narrators).
3. The Interpretation of one of the trusted Muslim scholars.

But what is mentioned here is not from those nor it has a proof we heard about:

2:168-169

> *O mankind, eat from whatever is on earth [that is] lawful and good and do not follow the footsteps of Satan. Indeed, he is to you a clear enemy.*
>
> *He only orders you to evil and immorality **and to say about Allah what you do not know.***